# Error: Can't resolve '@angular/compiler/src/core'

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn Angular 5 and after completing several tutorial I have purchased a [template](http://azimuth.themeseason.com/pages/dashboard) to help me learn how to structure my application.

I am trying to add my own module while following the structure of this template I purchased but I get the below message.

> ERROR in ./src/app/pages/property/property.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/compiler/src/core' in '....\myProject\src\app\pages\property'

[image]

My module definatly exists in that location so I feel I have have misunderstood how modules and components are referenced and how the routing is used.

I think the best way to try and get help here is by walking you through what I think is/should be happening.

**index.html**

index.html calls the component with the selector az-root, in this case `app.component`

```
...other stuff...
<az-root></az-root>
...other stuff...
```

**app.component.ts**

displays the default page defined in the `routes` property of `app.routing.ts`

```
...some imports...
@Component({
  selector: 'az-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template:`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**app.routing.ts**

loads the pages module located at `app/pages/pages.module.ts`

```
...some imports...
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
];
...other stuff...
```

**PagesModule**

i'm not sure how the `PagesModule` defines the `PagesComponent` because the `PagesComponent` selector is never called. But I have guessed that `pages.routing.ts` defines it

```
...some imports...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    SidebarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    PagesComponent
  ],
  providers:[
  ]
})
export class PagesModule { }
```

**pages.routing.ts**

displays the `pagesComponenet` which calls a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in its template. Under the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` of the `pagesComponenet` I would expect the propertyComponent to display but adding a  reference to my propertyModule in the `children` array I get the afore mentioned error, what have I done wrong?

```
...some imports
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', 
        component: PagesComponent,
        children:[
            { path:'', redirectTo:'property', pathMatch:'full' },
            { path: 'property', loadChildren: 'app/pages/property/property.module#PropertyModule' }
        ]
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**pages.component.ts**

```
...some  imports...
@Component({
  selector: 'az-pages',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './pages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pages.component.scss'],
  providers: [ AppState ]
})
export class PagesComponent implements OnInit {
...other stuff...
```

**pages.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">         
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="main">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Be careful with the auto import in vs code for angular, make sure that you are importing

`Component, NgModule` from `@angular/core`, **not** `@angular/compiler/src/core`

`@angular/compiler/src/core` is sometimes what gets inserted when you hit tab to auto-import

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Though for me VSCode added import of NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA from '@angular/compiler/src/core'.
Changing it to `import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'` fixed the problem.